# Error - An alias was previously found

Tags: mysql

An alias was previously found. (near "SUM" at position 42) this error

```
$qry2="SELECT count(".$rows->name.") AS count, SUM (".$rows->name.") As SUM FROM module4piechart";
```

[Here the CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoVEf.jpg) <<<                          [HERE THE ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBAYT.jpg)<<<

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: don't use alias name as SUM because its keyword

Comment: there my picture hlp me dude

Comment: your query failed due to some reason so that time your trying to fetch the result so it gives this error .

Comment: first of all echo $qry2;  copy and  paste and directly run in your database

Comment: show some additional code too

Comment: there my picture see upsite there hlp me ... i wan make a piechart for module

Comment: first of all echo $qry2; copy and paste and directly run in your database is it working ??

Comment: nope, error in `SUM`

Comment: 1 errors were found during analysis.

An alias was previously found. (near "`SUM`" at position 44)
SQL query: Documentation

SELECT count(HTML) AS `count` ,SUM (HTML)As `SUM` FROM module4piechart LIMIT 0, 25

MySQL said: Documentation

#1630 - FUNCTION mydb.SUM does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Comment: try this query remove space between function name and paranthesis . like this SELECT count(HTML) AS count1 ,SUM(HTML) As SUM1 FROM module4piechart

Comment: MySQL does not accept spaces between function name and parenthesis (unless you have set SQL_MODE=IGNORE_SPACE but that gives you other undesirable side effects)

Comment: omg thx u so much!!! work

Comment: happy to help you @Ck Wong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use keyword as alias name and follow the #San Lin Naing answer .

As per your comment error i give some clarification about that

> MySQL said: Documentation #1630 - FUNCTION mydb.SUM does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

```
SELECT count(HTML) AS count1 ,SUM(HTML) As SUM1 FROM module4piechart
```

MySQL does not accept spaces between function name and parenthesis (unless you have set SQL_MODE=IGNORE_SPACE but that gives you other undesirable side effects)

Use single quotes to escape the keywords

```
$qry2="SELECT count(".$rows->name.") AS 'count' ,SUM (".$rows->name.")As 'SUM' FROM module4piechart";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used `count` and `SUM` as an alias. Actually, `count` and `SUM` are SQL `Keyword`. You should avoid using `Keyword` in `SQL` query.

If you want to use `Keyword` as an alias by escaping, you must quoted with `'` single quotation mark or `"` double quotation mark. You can also use `` ` `` grave accent to escape keywords in `SQLite` and `MySQL`.

For your query,

```
$qry2="SELECT count(".$rows->name.") AS 'count' ,SUM (".$rows->name.")As 'SUM' FROM module4piechart";
```

and

```
$qry2="SELECT count(".$rows->name.") AS `count` ,SUM (".$rows->name.")As `SUM` FROM module4piechart";
```

may also work.

As another option, you can change alias to another name such as `count_name`, `sum_name`.

Comment: same problem cant